# Passing multiple data values from one JSP to another

Tags: java, jsp

I want to pass data in multiple rows belongs to the same column id from one JSP page to another.

When i use `request.getParameter("Name of the column id")` it retrieves only the first row.

How can i get values entered into all rows to my second JSP page?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `request.getParameterValues("name")` to get a `String[]` with all values (not just the first one.